# Question about surjective map of $R$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $M, N$ be two $R$-modules over a commutative ring with unit such that $M \subseteq N$, is it true that we can always find a surjective map $f : N \rightarrow M$? If not, under which hypothesis, this can be surely find?

Comment: Isn‘t $(x,y) \subseteq k[x,y]$ as $k[x,y]$-modules a counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true and it is unreasonable to demand as subobjects and quotient objects a priori behave quite differently.  I mentioned an easy example in the comments, namely $(x,y)_{k[x,y]} \subseteq k[x,y]$ as $k[x,y]$-modules. A morphism $f: k[x,y] \to (x,y)_{k[x,y]}$ is determined by $f(1)$ and in particular, every element in the image is divisible by $f(1)$. Hence, there is no way to hit both irreducible elements $x$ and $y$.

One condition in which there exists such a surjection that I can think of the top of my head is the following.

**Lemma.** Let $R$ be a PID and $N$ a finitely generated $R$-module. If $M \subseteq N$ is a submodule, then there exists an epic map $N \twoheadrightarrow M$.

*Proof.* Use the classification of finitely generated modules over PIDs and define the projection on each component. $\square$

Note that this is one bridge that had to be crossed for a counterexample. Our example was over $k[x,y]$, not a PID.

Comment: Good answer (+1). Another sufficient condition (on the subobject) : if $M\subset N$ and $M$ is injective, then there is a surjective map $N\twoheadrightarrow M$.